# FCFS calculation

Tags: algorithms

Hi im looking to calculate FCFS and wondering if anyone can help. 
I have the dataset of the process, serviceTIme and accessTime, could anyone explain how to calculate the start and end times. Sorry for a dumb question guys! just that i cannot find a clear example.

Thanks.

Comment: What is FCFS? What is the input to your problem, and what is the required output?